# Show that in a nilpotent group a subgroup of index $p^2$ is normal.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite, nilpotent group such that $|G|=p^2m$, where $p$ is prime and all prime divisors of $m$ are strictly greater than $p$. Show that if $H<G$ is a subgroup of index $p^2$, i.e. $|H|=m$, then $H$ is normal.

I've proven that the normalizer $N=N_G(H)$ strictly contains $H$, so the only thing I need to show now is that $N$ can't be of index $p$. How to do so? We would have $H\triangleleft N\triangleleft G$ but as $\triangleleft$ isn't necessarily transitive, this isn't enough to conclude.

Comment: Nilpotent is equivalent to all Sylow subgroups being normal, so you don't need nearly as strong assumptions as here.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Note that the group is of index $p^2$, not of order.

Comment: All Sylow subgroups being normal is the same as the group being the direct product of its Sylow subgroups, so complements to Sylow subgroups are also normal.

Comment: The point is that the factor $p^2$ is a distraction. You can  replace it by $p^k$ for any $k \ge 0$. Let $G$ be a finite, nilpotent group such that $|G|=p^km$, where $p$ is prime and all prime divisors of $m$ are distinct from  $p$. Then  if $H<G$ is a subgroup of index $p^k$, i.e. |$H|=m$, then $H$ is normal.

Comment: @DerekHolt Given that the group is assumed to be nilpotent, we really just need the prime divisors of $m$ to be distinct from $p$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, thanks - edited!